# Copy and Paste files as a user

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application there are some files. Which I want to be able to copy and paste elsewhere in application.

The file I want to copy and paste I have stored inside a function `GetPartialExportString()`

My Idea:

- When User clicks on "Copy" I create one file somewhere on comp and store it inside new created file
- When user clicks "Paste" I Read from the file I generated when I clicked copy and add it there.

```
    MemoryStream destinationStream = new MemoryStream();  
    protected void CopyCommand()
    {
        var modelAsString = GetPartialExportString();
        
        string fileName = "copy.xaml";
        string targetPath = @"C:\Users\";
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        //System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

        // convert string to stream
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(modelAsString);
        MemoryStream readingStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        readingStream.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
        readingStream.Close();

        readingStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);

        File.WriteAllText(destFile, modelAsString);
    }

    protected void PasteCommand()
    {
            string importString = File.ReadAllText("d:\\temp.txt");
            LoadUnitFromXamlString("d:\\temp.txt");
    }
```

It does not work like this. New to this, if someone can help I would appreciate!

File routes are incorect at the moment. But even when they were normal it was not working!

Comment: why bother with `streams`(which you probably not familiar) if you already have [File.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-5.0)? so you only need file names now.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should avoid overriding `Close()` method of `Stream` class for `MemoryStream`/`FileStream` objects. Use `Dispose()` instead.
2. You should get all the work done by the stream objects first and then dispose them.
3. After you've copied the contents of `readingStream` object to `file`, you'll have to readjust the position of stream buffer to the beginning of the contents present in `readingStream` object so as to copy it successfully to `destinationStream`.

Modify your code snippet like this:

```
readingStream.WriteTo(file);

readingStream.Position = 0;
readingStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);

file.Dispose();
readingStream.Dispose();

File.WriteAllText(destFile, modelAsString);
```